# Pandas create relations when importing to SQLite database?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Let's say i have two simple .csv files which i want to import into a SQLite database:

| id | state |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | State1 |
| 2 | State2 |
| 3 | State3 |

| id | district | values | state_fk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | District1 | 123 | 1 |
| 2 | District2 | 456 | 2 |
| 3 | District3 | 789 | 3 |

I receive an updated version of the `district` file every 2 weeks. I simply read the csv files and import/update them via `df.to_sql('table', con, if_exists='replace')`.

Is there a way in pandas to set a `PK-FK` relation between `states.id` and `districts.state_fk`?
I would like to regulary update the `district` table with new values and don't set the relation manually again after each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to create foreign keys with pandas. That is not what the module is for.

Instead of replacing the database table each time could you not first empty/truncate it using the sqlite3 module and then import your data using the if_exists='append' option ? Would look something like that :

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''TRUNCATE TABLE table''')
con.commit()
con.close()
df.to_sql('table', con, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Alright, thank you! So in order to create relations between my tables i would have to do the usual way via SQL statements outside of pandas? Thing is, the ``to_sql`` is pretty conveniente since it already creates the tables.

Comment: If you only replace the content of the table but not the table itself, the relationship between table won't be erased at each update so you you just have to create them once and then forget about it